# How do I get CID (Client ID) for the Expedia Affiliate Network?

Tags: api

I want to use Expedia's API on my website. I have registered on EAN (Expedia Affiliate Network), and now need an API key.

Now for the API key, I need CID(Client ID), which I don't have.

How do I get through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you have to fill this form and have to wait until they decide whether to give you access to their API or not.

**Note:** Confirmation period may be long for days and weeks.

Fill the registration for for Expedia API at [BECOME AN AFFILIATE - INQUIRY FORM](http://www.ean.com/contact-us)

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible since a few months. And accounts created before that did not convert to production are blocked.

Comment: means we should stop using Expedia's API??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to submit a manual request now: http://www.ean.com/contact-us